# Struts2/Dojo compatibility issues on IE

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, struts2, dojo

I designed a web app based on struts2. It works well in firefox but doesnt work anymore on the newer versions of IE. I get the following error on a dojo operation. Can anyone help please?

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;     SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 08:13:29 UTC
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 5814
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: https://mysite.com/myappName/struts     /dojo/struts_dojo.js.uncompressed.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to get rid of the Struts2 Dojo plugin, and to use a pure-Dojo library instead.

Struts2 Dojo plugin is:

- deprecated since Struts2 2.1.x
- way behind current Dojo releases
- buggy

let's try, you don't have a lot of work to do, just replace the import and see what happens.

Hope that helps.